# Add crontab job after at job is executed

Tags: linux, cron

I am pretty new to the VPS running on Linux 19.04.
I have already had a **at** job which will be executed on January 27 13:00:00 2020.

I am just wondering if there is any possible way to add a new `crontab` job after the **at** job is executed?

Let say I want to add a `crontab` job `0 0 * * * /usr/bin/pm2 restart Bot`, which will restart the Bot running with `pm2` at 00:00 every day.
If I want to manually add the `crontab` job is no problem, I just `crontab -e` and edit it in nano. But I want it to automatically add the `crontab` job after the `at` job is executed, or after 1 minute of `at` job is executed.

Comment: I understand the confusion, but the Linux command called **"at"** is not related to _AT Commands_ (which are commands used to communicate through a serial interface with a modem). For this reason I'm removing the `at-command` tag and adding `linux` tag (that could help you in obtaining help).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.